# Measuring Low Magnetic fields

Tags: current-measurement, measurement, hall-effect, magnetic-flux

Im working on a project where I want to measure low magnetic fields in a wire. The range I want to measure is 0.1 - 10 mG or 0.01 - 1 µT in low frequencies (DC - 500Hz) (This range (0.1 - 10 mG) can be larger but I want a accurate measurement in this range).

I looked into hall sensors and current sensors that use the hall effect but these are for larger fields most of the time (and large currents). I thought about using a current clamp and calculating the magnetic field from that, but that relies on the distance from the wire (and with these small field you make it really inaccurate).

At what other things should I look so I can move on in this project?

Comment: How do you expect to measure a magnetic field in a wire? What is the measuring setup?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might look at the [Fluxgate Magnetometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer#Fluxgate_magnetometer) More details [here](http://www.sensorland.com/HowPage071.html) and a [DIY project here](http://motivationtolearn.org/wordpress/?p=1347)

It is not a particularly hard project if you know some basic electronics, or maybe you could buy a readymade one, although they are going to be a lot more expensive than the Hall Effect one you get in phones. However, they can measure down to the nano-Teslas

> A fluxgate magnetometer consists of a small, magnetically susceptible
>   core wrapped by two coils of wire. An alternating electric current is
>   passed through one coil, driving the core through an alternating cycle
>   of magnetic saturation; i.e., magnetised, unmagnetised, inversely
>   magnetised, unmagnetised, magnetised, and so forth. This constantly
>   changing field induces an electric current in the second coil, and
>   this output current is measured by a detector. In a magnetically
>   neutral background, the input and output currents match. However, when
>   the core is exposed to a background field, it is more easily saturated
>   in alignment with that field and less easily saturated in opposition
>   to it. Hence the alternating magnetic field, and the induced output
>   current, are out of step with the input current. The extent to which
>   this is the case depends on the strength of the background magnetic
>   field. Often, the current in the output coil is integrated, yielding
>   an output analog voltage, proportional to the magnetic field.

Comment: Still it doesn't answer how the OP will measure the magnetic field in the wire and how would this fluxgate measure the field independently from a measuring distance.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič Measure the field from set distances from the wire, and then back calculate.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I looked into some fluxgate sensors and they can be way more accurate than a hall effect sensor. So I marked Dirks answer as an answer so I can further do my research, because I dont know yet if this sensor will be the one that is going to work. But he gave the answer on the question I had :)

Comment: @NoëlVissers Your question is not understandable, what you are really looking for? In the meantime you have accepted an answer, just because a fluxgate sensor is more accurate than hall sensor. Still, you are not able to measure a magnetic field in the wire, and the measurement is distance dependent. Also that clamp meter is dependent on distance is wrong,...

Comment: @MarkoBuršič my question "At what other things should I look so I can move on in this project?" is pretty clear. I already said I got a good answer. I never said a clamp is distance dependent. The magnetic field calculation is distance dependent though, If you calculate from current to magnetic field.

Comment: @NoëlVissers Not sure what your setup is, but if you have a long enough wire you can simply wind it in a coil to increase the field